# How to use combination of keys to call custom methods in CK Editor using 'key' event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need to call one custom method with the combination of keys like "CTRL + P" in CK Editor. I tried for single key press event like an "Enter" and its working but my requirement is to be with combination of keys. Is there any way to achieve it?

```
                            ev.editor.on( 'key', function( e ) {
                                var evtobj = window.event ? event : e
                                if( evtobj.data.keyCode === 13 ) {
                                    ev.editor.execCommand( 'addCustomWidget' );
                                }
                            } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setKeystroke()](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setKeystroke)

> Assigns keystrokes associated with editor commands.

Αssuming you have an CKEditor instance named `editor1`:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    evt.editor.setKeystroke(CKEDITOR.CTRL + 80, 'addCustomWidget'); // CTRL + P
});
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Basically, you use the `instanceReady` event to set the keystroke.